# CC1120 does not receive upon software upgrade

Tags: wireless, msp430, texas-instruments, sub-1

**Note: only read if you have experience using Texas Instruments CC1120 modules earlier.**

I am using [this](http://www.ti.com/tool/smartrftrxebk) development board by Texas Instruments with a CC1120 module hooked up on it.

I have been using the TrxEB RF PER Test Software (Rev. C) on it and I have been able to transmit packets to another module in the RX Sniff Mode successfully. However, today I upgraded to the CC112x Software Examples (Rev. E) software which allows me to directly enter RX Sniff Mode (there's a separate app for it) instead of having to navigate through a menu. Both of these firmware can be found [here](http://www.ti.com/tool/cc1125dk) (scroll down to the Software section).

Note: Rev. E firmware is a bit difficult to compile because of it's folder hierarchy, I have uploaded a cleaner version of it [here](https://github.com/usamamuneeb/CC112x-TrxEB-SampleCodes).

The transmitter is working fine and I can see transmissions at 868 MHz using a lab spectrum analyzer, however, the packets do not show up at the receiver end.

I had issues transmitting at high frequencies earlier so I switched to 434 MHz in Rev. C firmware (which had a menu). However, I must change some registers in order to do the same in Rev. E firmware.

I have been searching around and the registers that control the transmission frequency appear to be controlled by the following set of values:

```cpp
    //Register Settings for different frequency bands.
    static uint8 freqSettings[5][3] = 
    { 
      {0x69,0xF1,0xFF}, // 169.5125 MHz
      {0x6C,0x80,0x00}, // 434 MHz
      {0x6C,0x80,0x00}, // 868 MHz   
      {0x72,0x60,0x00}, // 915 MHz
      {0x77,0x60,0x00}  // 955 MHz
    };
```

I'm surprised that 434 MHz and 868 MHz use the same values (these values are from the Rev. C firmware. Then there is this:

```cpp
    //Band select setting for LO divider
    static uint8 cc112xFsCfgs[5] = 
    {
      0x0A, // 169 MHz 
      0x04, // 434 MHz  
      0x02, // 868 MHz 
      0x02, // 915 MHz 
      0x02, // 955 MHz   
    };
```

Unfortunately, the register this array controls is `CC112X_FS_CFG` which is set to `0x12` by default in the newer firmware, a value that matches neither 434 MHz nor 868 MHz.

Anyone who has successfully been able to transmit at a different frequency using CC1120 wireless module?

Comment: I haven't used this development board but I've used instead CC1120 modules connected through CCDebugger to a computer running SmartRFStudio software. SmartRFStudio will give you all the registers values for every possible configuration (even the CC1120 datasheet refers to this software). Hope this helps!

Comment: The 24 bits of the Freq register are the multiplier applied to the LO to reach the desired frequency. 868MHz cannot have the same value as 433MHz.

Comment: I guess you are right. I too used SmartRF Studio to find which register changed when I changed the frequency. It turned out the `CC112X_FS_CFG` takes different values for both.

Answer (score 1):

I found the answer to this and would like to get back here.

The difference between 434 MHz and 868 MHz is the `CC112X_FS_CFG` register which is set to `0x12` for 868 MHz and at `0x14` for 434 MHz.

I fixed it and it started working like a charm.